# Is there a quick way to copy an entire section in TexStudio

Tags: sectioning, texstudio

I wonder if there is a quick way to copy the entire content of a section in TexStudio. When clicking on the arrow key to the left of a section, it will encapsulate the section. But when copying the selection of it, only the title of the section is copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a quick video :): In order to get **complete Section A**, just **select Section A to Section B** when **Section A** is **collapsed**.

**Important:** You select TWO sections in order to select the first section completely.

[image]

[image]

### Additional Video

[image]

Comment: This way can only copy the title of a section, not the content of it. I need to copy the entire content within the section too.

Comment: @hermes No, please have a close look at the video. The content of Section A is also copied! I cannot be more explicit than providing a screen video.

Comment: @hermes I added an additional screenshot that "proves" that the complete section is selected.

Comment: It should copy on the section on the left structure panel. You can modify the video.

Comment: @hermes I do not understand your comment and I do not have more time (doing a Python project now, enough procrastination for today :)). Still, I do not understand why you're not happy with the answer because it seems to answers your question and it looks like a 10 sec. effort.

Comment: From my experience, you can not copy a selection of a section on the document (right screen) because it only copies the title of the section. You need to copy the section 
 on the left screen (structure panel) so that the entire content of the section is selected and copied.

Comment: @hermes I added another video that shows it even clearer. Please show your own video in case that does not work for you.

Comment: I am not sure what happens. Anyway, I accept your answer

Comment: Very clever. Also works for texmaker. Fold the section and include the next line of text that comes afterwards in your marked text - you will then be able to cut/copy... all that is in-between.